# CSS issue in positioning element

Tags: css, layout, html, positioning

I can't seem to get the graphics on the top and the bottom of the navigation menu to have no gaps.  Since the top and bottom images need to be stretched it can't be done as a background image.  The 3 pieces need to be touching.  I have tried using tables, setting margins and padding to 0px on everything, even tried using a css clear file and I still cannot get them touching.

**jsFiddle...**  http://jsfiddle.net/PerryCS/JXVGM/1/

Am I trying to force the browser to do something it's not capable of doing?  Where is the extra spacing coming from?

Please and thank you!

I don't mind trying things out.  I have spent about 11 hours fiddling with this and I'm very frustrated at the lack of understanding on my part at why there is still a space.  Ugh.

Needs to work on IE7 and above please.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: block` to `.navribbon img`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/JXVGM/2/

Comment: WOW!  If you only knew how happy I am right now....  If I could reach through the internet and give you a hug I would!  :) LOL.   11 hours of frustration and it's one simple thing I missed.  It works great!   THANK YOU!.

Comment: So... to try and understand why it didn't work...  an IMG tag i suppose is an INLINE block and by adding CSS to make it a BLOCK it behaves differently?  Am I correct?

Comment: Correct. When the `img` was `inline`, it was aligned on the baseline (check the image [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender)). This shows it: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/JXVGM/8/

Comment: OH!   Thanks for that link!  That explains something else I was curious about.  More gaps in my knowledge filled in!   :)  How I wish I could plug into your brain and copy your knowledge!  LOL.   Have a nice day!  Much appreciated for spending some time to help me!